# PC doesn't connect to the internet automatically

Tags: networking

Since about 2 weeks ago my PC doesn't connect to the internet automatically.

I have to use `ipconfig /release` -> `/renew` combo every time on startup to get access. It only happens on the initial booting of the PC and router, restarting the PC when the internet is already working doesn't give the same issue.

Also, I can't ping anything (including myself), as in there are no timeout messages, the cmd just blanks out and doesn't respond to anything else.

Same thing with tracert. It shows the first hop as empty and doesn't progress any further. I already tried flushing DNS and I got no clue on how to approach this further.

[image: cmd commands here]

Comment: (A) Run TCP/IP Reset  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the compute.
  (B) Update / Reinstall the Network Adapter.

Comment: What is the output of `ipconfig /all` and `arp -a` before and after?